# Local Time Issue In AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, utc

I have my `NodeJS` in `AWS pm2 Server` which is located on `N.Virginia`. I am getting a date from user and returning them with the response.

**Code**

```
my_date = '2019-09-17T18:30:00Z'
var date = moment.utc(my_date).local().format('MMM-DD');
console.log(date);
```

When I do with my local server(India) value of `date` is `Sep-18`. When I do with AWS server, the value of date is `Sep-17`. How to overcome this issue ? Is there is any way to sort this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

Also make sure NTPd is running.